# Go back to HTTP_REFERER after POST and redirect

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, redirect, ruby-on-rails-4, back

I have an update POST request that upon successful completion, will redirect back to the edit screen that is was triggered on.

I arrive at the edit page initially via a button on a specific study page that belongs to a user. I can successfully navigate `:back` to the page that I came from with another button on this edit page.

However, after the POST request the http_referer has obviously changed to become the 'edit' screen. I would like to display another button to the user if I have recently performed a POST request that will bring them back to the page they came from before they submitted the POST request.

This would take the form of the following(roughly):

```
<% if "I have just performed the update action" %>
  <%= link_to "the study that I came from" %>
<% else %>
  <%= link_to 'Back', :back %>
<% end %>
```

Anyone know how I can implement this or if its even possible by saving parameters, via cookies, via the session history or via any method? Thanks.